# XSLT 2.0 Grouping, Summing, Counting and Conditions

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have XSLT that is grouping the input, summing the current-group, and only outputting a record if the sum meets a certain condition.  The for-each-group works fine, but I can't get an accurate record count for a trailer record.

Here's a sample input:

```
<Book_Data>
  <Book_Entry>
    <Book>
      <Book_ID>1</Book_ID>
      <Book_Name>Test1</Book_Name>
    </Book>
    <Sales>
      <Quantity>2</Quantity>
    </Sales>
  <Book_Entry>
  <Book_Entry>
    <Book>
      <Book_ID>1</Book_ID>
      <Book_Name>Test1</Book_Name>
    </Book>
    <Sales>
      <Quantity>3</Quantity>
    </Sales>
  <Book_Entry>
  <Book_Entry>
    <Book>
      <Book_ID>2</Book_ID>
      <Book_Name>Test2</Book_Name>
    </Book>
    <Sales>
      <Quantity>3</Quantity>
    </Sales>
  <Book_Entry>
  <Book_Entry>
    <Book>
      <Book_ID>2</Book_ID>
      <Book_Name>Test2</Book_Name>
    </Book>
    <Sales>
      <Quantity>-3</Quantity>
    </Sales>
  <Book_Entry>
</Book_Data>
```

And here is a sample XSLT (2.0):

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="Book_Data/Book_Entry" group-by="Book/Book_ID">
        <xsl:if test="sum(current-group()/Sales/Quantity) != 0">
            <xsl:value-of select="Book/Book_ID"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="Book/Book_Name"/>
        </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each-group>

<xsl:value-of select="count(distinct-values(Book_Data/Book_Entry/Book/Book_ID[sum(../../Sales/Quantity) != 0]))"/>
```

The problem is the top section correctly outputs only book 1.  But the trailer counts both books, and I can't figure out how to condition the sum to reference a Book_ID in the outer context.

Comment: Please show the expected output (surely you don't mean to pile up strings like that?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store the resulting output of the `for-each-group` in a variable and then count the groups, if I understand what you want:

```
    <xsl:variable name="groups" as="xs:string*">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="Book_Data/Book_Entry" group-by="Book/Book_ID">
            <xsl:if test="sum(current-group()/Sales/Quantity) != 0">
                <xsl:sequence select="current-grouping-key()"/>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each-group>          
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:value-of select="$groups"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="count($groups)"/>
```

Comment: Hi Martin,

Thanks for the quick and clever response.  Unfortunately in condensing my problem I left out some important detail.  Namely the for-each-group outputs more than 1 item which I think makes your method not work.  I updated the question to reflect this.

Comment: You could create temporary output from the grouping using a wrapper element for each group, then (a) strip the wrappers for the final output and (b) count the wrappers for the report footer.

Comment: @RyanB, see whether Michael's comment helps solving it, if not, then edit your question and show exactly which output you want to create, currently it is not clear whether you really want the `for-each-group` to simply spit up lots of unstructured strings.

Comment: Yes, that does help me see how to solve it.  I can create one for-each-group inside a variable for counting and another for-each-group for the output.  Thanks!

Comment: @RyanB You only need to group the nodes once. Then you use the result (stored in a variable) twice: once as the actual output, and once as the sequence to count.

Comment: You don't need two separate for-each-groups, you can use e.g. http://xsltransform.net/3NSSEvH to group and output the group and the count.