# How to transform an XML document using XSLT

Tags: xslt

I need to take an XML file and create a new output file.
During creation of the output file, I need to total the quantities by material

This is my input file: -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<data-set xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <record>
        <MATERIAL>Material1</MATERIAL>
        <SALES_DIST>FS</SALES_DIST>
        <REGION>North</REGION>
        <FIELDNM001>EA</FIELDNM001>
        <MONTH>2020-01-01</MONTH>
        <FIELDNM002>1</FIELDNM002>
    </record>
    <record>
        <MATERIAL>Material1</MATERIAL>
        <SALES_DIST>FS</SALES_DIST>
        <REGION>North</REGION>
        <FIELDNM001>EA</FIELDNM001>
        <MONTH>2020-01-01</MONTH>
        <FIELDNM002>1</FIELDNM002>
    </record>
</data-set>
```

What I need to end up with is a file like this: -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<data-set xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <record>
        <MATERIAL>Material1</MATERIAL>
        <SALES_DIST>FS</SALES_DIST>
        <REGION>North</REGION>
        <FIELDNM001>EA</FIELDNM001>
        <MONTH>2020-01-01</MONTH>
        <FIELDNM002>2</FIELDNM002>
    </record>
</data-set>
```

Any ideas on what the xslt document should look like to achieve this?

Many thanks in advance.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<data-set xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <record>
        <MATERIAL>Material1</MATERIAL>
        <SALES_DIST>FS</SALES_DIST>
        <REGION>North</REGION>
        <FIELDNM001>EA</FIELDNM001>
        <MONTH>2020-01-01</MONTH>
        <FIELDNM002>2</FIELDNM002>
    </record>
</data-set>
```

Comment: This is a *grouping* question. Do a search - it's probably the most often asked XSLT question here. Note that answers are different for XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Starting from [this reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29832511/how-to-get-the-sum-of-node-values-in-xslt), the following works for me using xsltproc on Linux:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:gt="http://www.gtech.com/lsp/2009-09-23"
                exclude-result-prefixes="gt">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <data-set xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <record>
                <MATERIAL><xsl:value-of select="//MATERIAL" /></MATERIAL>
                <SALES_DIST><xsl:value-of select="//SALES_DIST" /></SALES_DIST>
                <REGION><xsl:value-of select="//REGION" /></REGION>
                <FIELDNM001><xsl:value-of select="//FIELDNM001" /></FIELDNM001>
                <MONTH><xsl:value-of select="//MONTH" /></MONTH>
                <FIELDNM002><xsl:value-of select="sum(//FIELDNM002[.])"/></FIELDNM002>
            </record>
        </data-set>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If other fields of the records in xml are not equals, it takes only the first records' values

Comment: Thanks Manticore.
That works a treat.
However, as is often the case in the world of development, the goalposts have moved on me.
I now need to total the quantity (FIELDNM002) when the <MATERIAL> tag AND the <MONTH> tag are the same.
There could potentially be the same material occurring multiple times where the month values are different.
So I need to group by Material and Month.
I tried playing around with what you provided but can't seem to get it to work :(

Comment: your question was not complete then. Did you downvote ?

Comment: No, I didn't down vote.
Still not sure how all this works to be honest.
Thy moved the goalposts on me though so I now need to group by 2 fields rather than one.
Any idea how I can do that?

Comment: Although this is already 8 months ago, did you read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42250394/xslt-2-0-grouping-summing-counting-and-conditions? But I guess you already solved the problem.